# How to unittest that a exception was raised without raising so that the program terminates

Tags: python

According to a requirement I need to unittest that an exception has been raised (SearchMiss).
I can do this with assertRaises surely. But the second requirement is that the exception should be raised, but the program should not be terminated / crash when it's raised.

If I don't add the re-raise part in the exception block, the program won't terminate but then the unittest says that the exception was not raised.

Suggestions on how to do this? Should I use another test method?

I'm raising the exception like this:

```
   def find_word(self, word):
        """ Checks if given word exists """
        try:
            if self.trie.find_word(word): # Checks if word exists first
                return True  # Returns bool, true if found else false
            raise SearchMiss
        except SearchMiss:
            SearchMiss.print_error()
            raise ## If I delete this raise the program won't crash but the test case will fail
            return false
```

Testcase:

```
   def test_raise_search_miss(self):
        """ Tests raise search miss """
        with self.assertRaises(SearchMiss):
            self.spellchecker.delete_word("")
```

Note: The spellchecker delete_word method is calling the find_word method that raises the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could include the exact requirement that you are trying to meet.

From what you wrote, I would think that you shouldn't have a try/except within `find_word`.  Let `find_word` raise SearchMiss.  Then, your unit test can check that it does so.

Separately, when you call `find_word` from `delete_word`, wrap it in a try/except so that it doesn't terminate your program.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. Will accept this answer, as soon as it's possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Then you don't have to test the `delete_word` method alone, you have to test the broader context where it is run. That is, your test should place a call to other functions/methods that will ultimately call `delete_word` with the faulty argument.

It would not technically be a "unit test" anymore, however, if you can write a test with no colateral effects (expecting an incoming HTTP connection, or committing to a database) that can do this, you could put the test in the same file with no problems.